# Using ng2-charts, how to "zoom out"?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, ng2-charts

"Zooming" is not the correct word, but I can't find any other more suitable word for what I am looking for.

Currently, I have this result: 
[image]

As you can see, the horizontal annotation labels are cut in half due to the value of the chart being in the interval.

I would like the chart to "zoom out" so that I can read the annotation labels. Note that I am not looking for dynamic zooming with mouse wheel or whatever. I just want the view to include Y values a bit superior and inferior to what they currently are.

An example of desired result (with extrem paint skills):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer of your problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951109/ng2-charts-how-to-set-fixed-range-for-y-axis). You can just modify the options of your chart. Please let me know if it does not work and provide some code then. Then I can try to give you a working example.